# Every element of $S_n$ can be written as a product of transpositions of the form $(1 i )$, for various $i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

> Let $n \geq 2$. Show that every element of $S_n$ can be written as a product of
> transpositions of the form $(1 i )$, for various $i$.

I have proved by induction that if $n \geq 2$, then every permutation in $S_n$ is a product of transpositions. Using the following, if $\sigma=(123\cdots k ) $ then $(123\cdots k )= (1k)(1(k-1))\cdots(12)$. But I don't know how to relate what I have to this exercise.  How could I finish the proof?

Comment: Hint: I think your $\sigma$ is a red herring. Try thinking about this property: if $i \neq j$, then $(i\,j) = (1\,i)(1\,j)(1\,i)$.

Comment: Generators of symmetric groups have been considered in the site before. Have you tried using the search function?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The truth I still don't know how to use that function

Comment: Hopmaths, Pedro is right. I doesn't look like you would try to search before posting. This site has many excellent answers, and people spend a lot of time for it. So it is worth to look for the answers of your questions, before asking the same question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each non-trivial transposition $(a\;b)=(1\;a)(1\;b)(1\;a)$ lies in $\langle\mathcal N\rangle$ where $$\mathcal N=\{(1\;i):1\leq i\leq n\}$$ This demonstrates why $\mathcal S_n=\langle\mathcal N\rangle$ because every permutation is a product of transpositions.

Comment: Your first equation doesn't hold when $a = b \neq 1$. This doesn't affect the end result.

Comment: @RobArthan. Thank you. It suffices to qualify $(a\;b)$ as "non-trivial". I've made the edit.